# How does Python JSON library dealing with time?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

So I'm currently learning MongoDB and I'm using PyMongo rather than MongoDB shell.

When I started trying the basic CRUD operations, I found it is hard to load the `bios` data using PyMongo, since the original data posted on the [website](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bios-example-collection/) had a strange `ISODATA` for `time`.

The original python `JSON` library seemed to be not support this and the `mongoimport` seemed to be not support this either(not sure). But I found [this](https://github.com/robertmirro/mongodb-sandbox/blob/master/bios.json), after modifying into `{$date:"2017-04-01T05:00:00Z"}`, `mongoimport` was working.

Right now I'm using `subprocess` to call a external command to import the data. So my question is, how to use python correctly read the JSON data and using PyMongo to insert the data.

#### Details

the `bios` data in the mongodb documentation looks like this

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"name" : {
    "first" : "John",
    "last" : "Backus"
},
"birth" : ISODate("1924-12-03T05:00:00Z"),
"death" : ISODate("2007-03-17T04:00:00Z"),
"contribs" : [
    "Fortran",
    "ALGOL",
    "Backus-Naur Form",
    "FP"
],
"awards" : [
    {
        "award" : "W.W. McDowell Award",
        "year" : 1967,
        "by" : "IEEE Computer Society"
    },
    {
        "award" : "National Medal of Science",
        "year" : 1975,
        "by" : "National Science Foundation"
    },
    {
        "award" : "Turing Award",
        "year" : 1977,
        "by" : "ACM"
    },
    {
        "award" : "Draper Prize",
        "year" : 1993,
        "by" : "National Academy of Engineering"
    }
]
}
```

And when I try to parse it with Python's JSON library, I get a error message`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` because of the `"birth" : ISODate("1924-12-03T05:00:00Z"),`. And `mongoimport` can not parse this because of the same reason.

When I modified,

`"birth" : ISODate("1924-12-03T05:00:00Z"),` into

`"birth" : $date:"2017-04-01T05:00:00Z"`

`mongoimport` was working but python still wasn't able to parse it.

What I am asking here is a way to deal this problem within Python and PyMongo rather than calling a external commands.

Comment: Please share an example of *how* you were attempting to insert the data using pymongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example that you're looking at was probably intended to be used within the mongo shell, where the use of the ISODate bson type can be parsed as shown.

Outside of that, we have the challenge that JSON does not have a date datatype, nor does it have a standard way of representing dates. To deal with this challenge, MongoDB created something called [Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/), which can encode dates in JSON similar to how you have shown with `$date`.

In order to work with Extended JSON in Python / PyMongo, you could use [json_util](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/api/bson/json_util.html).

Here's a brief example:

```
from bson.json_util import loads
from pymongo import MongoClient

json = '''
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : {
        "first" : "John",
        "last" : "Backus"
    },
    "birth" : {"$date":"2017-04-01T05:00:00.000Z"},
    "death" : {"$date":"2017-04-01T05:00:00.000Z"}
}
'''

bson = loads(json)
print(str(bson))
db = MongoClient().test
collection = db.bios
collection.insert(bson)
```

Comment: that is exactly what I'm looking for! thanks a lot. But how do you deal with `"_id":ObjectId("42")`?, is it `"_id":{"ObjectId":"42"}`? I find my way seems not right.

Comment: $oid see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#oid on the page I referenced